# Pattern matching against value constructors in type variables / some sort of flexible function-polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Let’s say I have the algebraic data type of a binary tree defined as:

```hs
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

To build trees, I now want to define a function `(-<)` such that I can create trees like this:

```
1-<(2,3)      1-<(2-<(3,4),5)      1-<(Empty,2-<(4,5))
  1                 1                        1
 / \               / \                        \
2   3             2   5                        2
                 / \                          / \
                3   4                        4   5
```

It seems it impossible! My reasoning is that it must have type signature `a -> (a, a) -> Tree a)`. I then thought that it might be possible to interpret something of type `a` either as `Tree b` for some other type `b` or, if that fails, plainly as `a`. In the same manner I tried to define

```hs
f :: a -> Int
f (Just _) = 1
f _ = 0
```

which would be a function that told me whether a value is of type `Maybe a` and constructed by `Just` or not. But this doesn’t work – ghc then wants the type signature to be `Maybe a -> Int`.

Unless I don’t know of any special feature in Haskell, what I want is impossible. My questions now are:

- Is it? Or do I miss something?
- What would be a good approximation to what I want? (I want to go for succintness, so e.g. writing `(Right 2 -<(Right 3, Left (Right 4 -<(Right 1, Right 5)))` is no solution.)

P.S. I really don’t know how to title this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a class which does what you want pretty easily:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, 
  FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, TypeFamilies, OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show

class Leaf a b | a -> b where
    leaf :: a -> b

instance Leaf (Tree a) (Tree a) where leaf = id

instance (d ~ Tree c) => Leaf c d where leaf a = Node a Empty Empty

mkTree a (b,c) = Node a (leaf b) (leaf c)
```

The only problem with this approach is that due to defaulting rules, things like `mkTree 1 (1,2)` will fail because the integer literals are polymorphic, whereas `mkTree (1 :: Int) ((1 :: Int),(2 :: Int))` will work. You can make it 'work' with fully polymorphic types by turning on `IncoherentInstances` but this makes things behave even more strangely so it isn't the best solution.

You mentioned you want a succinct syntax and the 2nd option is only slightly less succinct but will always work when it should instead of giving cryptic type errors, including with fully polymorphic types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    MultiParamTypeClasses
  , FlexibleInstances
  , FunctionalDependencies
  #-}

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show

data L a = L a 

class Leaf' a b | a -> b where
    leaf' :: a -> b

instance Leaf' (L a) (Tree a) where
    leaf' (L a) = Node a Empty Empty

instance Leaf' (Tree a) (Tree a) where
    leaf' = id

mkTree' a (b,c) = Node a (leaf' b) (leaf' c)

>1-<(L 2,L 3)
Node 1 (Node 2 Empty Empty) (Node 3 Empty Empty)
>1-<(2-<(L 3,L 4),L 5)
Node 1 (Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty) (Node 4 Empty Empty)) (Node 5 Empty Empty)
>1-<(Empty,2-<(L 4,L 5))
Node 1 Empty (Node 2 (Node 4 Empty Empty) (Node 5 Empty Empty))
```

Comment: I need to have a look at this tomorrow! Now I go to sleep. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I don’t understand what’s going on, but this seems indeed very interesting. However, I notice that it works. This is great and very surprising! It’s good to know that you *can* bend ghc to do stuff like this. Thanks! I will accept this answer for this reason – it’s the most interesting one and it aswers my first queston (semi-)positively.

Comment: If you want to have a better understanding, you should read the sections of the user manual pertaining to functional dependancies and multiparameter typeclasses: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html

Answer (score 5):

You could just create three different operators:

```
(-<) :: a -> (a, a) -> Tree a
p -< (l, r) = Node p (Node l Empty Empty) (Node r Empty Empty)

(-<\) :: a -> (Tree a, a) -> Tree a
p -<\ (lt, r) = Node p lt (Node r Empty Empty)

(-</) :: a -> (a, Tree a) -> Tree a
p -</ (l, rt) = Node p (Node l Empty Empty) rt
```

then your trees can be expressed as

```
1-<(2,3)
1-<\(2-<(3,4),5)
```

and

```
1-<\(Empty,2-<(4,5))
```

Comment: I thought of that, too, and it seems to be the best solution so far. One would also need a forth one `(-<|):: a-> (Tree a, Tree a) -> Tree a`. Thanks! Your last one wouldn’t work, I think, and you’d need `(-<|)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The function you seek can't have type `a -> (a, a) -> Tree a)` in Haskell; it simply isn't well-typed at all. The reason is that those `a`s could be any type at all, so you can't use their values in any operation that needs a property of any specific type (such as checking whether they are an `Empty` or `Node` value).

The function you're asking for is also ambiguously defined when you remember that you can put trees inside trees, and so a possibility for those `a`s could actually be `Tree b`. For example, if I tried `Empty -< (Empty, Empty)` to make a `Tree (Tree t)` (for some `t`), is this supposed to return `Node Empty Empty Empty` where I interpret the `(Empty, Empty)` as a pair of trees, or `Node (Node Empty Empty) (Node Empty Empty)` where I interpret the `(Empty, Empty)` as a pair of "bare values" that need to be turned into leaf nodes? (Or one of the other permutations?)

You could design a language so that this ambiguity is resolvable, but Haskell avoids the issue by making values in a completely arbitrary type (like `a`) completely opaque. You basically can't do anything at all with such a value other than pass it on to another function that accepts a completely arbitrary type; this can seem limiting, but this is actually a key part of how Haskell types work and responsible for a lot of the safety guarantees that make a lot of generic library code work.

So what you need is for every position to be expecting an `a`, or a `Tree a`; it's not possible to accept an "anything" and see whether it is a `Tree a`. One way to do that is to use a family of functions that covers all the possibilities, as in Lee's answer. That's a lot less fun if there are more than two positions! Another possibility is to *only* accept trees and use a projection function that turns "bare values" into singleton trees<sup>1</sup>. e.g.

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

(-<) :: a -> (Tree a, Tree a) -> Tree a
x -< (l, r) = Node x l r

t :: a -> Tree a
t x = Node x Empty Empty
```

Then you are effectively resolving the ambiguity I mentioned above by using `t` to "tag" everything that needs to be turned into a tree, while everything without the tag must already be a tree of the correct type.

Your examples would then be written as:

```
*Main> 1 -< (t 2, t 3)
Node 1 (Node 2 Empty Empty) (Node 3 Empty Empty)
*Main> 1 -< (2 -< (t 3, t 4), t 5)
Node 1 (Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty) (Node 4 Empty Empty)) (Node 5 Empty Empty)
*Main> 1 -< (Empty, 2 -< (t 4, t 5))
Node 1 Empty (Node 2 (Node 4 Empty Empty) (Node 5 Empty Empty))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is basically the `return` function you would write if you were making `Tree` into a monad, but `return` is a bit long to sprinkle all through your succinct tree expressions, and seems unrelated to tree-making, so I think a better/shorter name is helpful here (`t` isn't necessarily great, but it's short and I wasn't feeling terribly inspired).